# Problems with URL's size

Tags: fontsize, urls

I would like to change the font size of the URLs in my latex document.
I did:

```
\begin{document}
...
\usepackage{url}

Figure 1: \scriptsize{\url{my url}}\\
Figure 2: \scriptsize{\url{my url}}
...
```

The problem is that these commands make the font size of the "Figure 2" also in `\scriptsize` and I don't want that.

Can someone help me?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) The font changing commands don't take an argument, but are "declarations": `{\scriptsize\url{...}}` should do.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to [`url`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/url), a quick fix would be to redefine `\UrlFont`, perhaps as follows

```
\renewcommand{\UrlFont}{\scriptsize}
```

However, the documentation also says that it would be better to define your own `url-style` (which would be a bit more involved).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{url}

\renewcommand{\UrlFont}{\scriptsize}

\begin{document}

Figure 1: \url{my url}

Figure 2: \url{my url}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This will change the size of *all* URLs in the document

Comment: @egreg indeed, that was my intention :) the OP said that he would like to change the size of 'the urls'

Comment: Although not economical, you could use `\newcommand{\URL}[1][\scriptsize]{\renewcommand{\UrlFont}{#1}\url}`, which allows you to use `\URL[\normalsize]{...}` for fun.

Comment: For me the best solution was to use `\let\OldUrlFont\UrlFont \renewcommand{\UrlFont}{\small\OldUrlFont}` instead, which allows to keep the URL format and just adds your prefered font size.